# MVC5 anonymous access failing for new pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm a noob when it comes to MVC security as I usually use my own, so please bear with me.

I have an MVC5 application which I'm using pretty-much straight out of the box.

It all works fine when I run it locally but after I have deployed it to a remote webserver I have authentication issues.

The pages which come with the project as standard open fine (Home, About, etc) but when I try to open one of my own I get this error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.

The error is being raised on the first line of the view that tries to reference the model.

I haven't added anything to the web.config to allow or deny authentication.

An extract from the config looks like this:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="LessAssetHandler" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="BundleTransformer.Less.HttpHandlers.LessAssetHandler, BundleTransformer.Less" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
  </handlers>
      <security>
          <authorization>
              <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
          </authorization>
      </security>
</system.webServer>
```

What do I need to do to allow access to the other pages?

[Edit]

The Home controller works fine. It is the standard out-of-the-box one which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ASP.NET_MVC5_Bootstrap3_3_1_LESS.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have a global `AuthorizationFilter` and an `AllowAnonymous` filter attribute on "standard" controllers ?

Comment: The Home controller doesn't have the `AllowAnonymous` filter and that works fine. I searched the whole solution for `AuthorizationFilter` but didn't find it.

Comment: The Home controller doesn't have the `AllowAnonymous` filter and that works fine. I searched the whole solution for `AuthorizationFilter` but didn't find it.

Comment: (Added code for home controller)

Answer (score 0):

This was a SQL server problem, not ASP authentication as I had thought.

The server name in the connection string was the fully qualified version, e.g.:

> server.domain.local

Changing this to its short version `server` fixed this issue!